# Why Pycharm returns an up arrow instead of cleaning screen?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pycharm

I use PyCharm as my IDE. I use console in PyCharm and I want to clean screen by:

```
>>>2+2
4
>>>print("example")
example
>>>from os import system
>>>system("cls")
0
```

Before 0 I see an arrow, but console isn't cleared. Same situation with the scripts. 
It works on basic python shell.

Answer (score 2):

PyCharm has two different consoles.

The **Terminal** that runs Command prompt in Windows and **Python Console** that runs project interpreter with helper script `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.2.4\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py`.

#### Terminal

To clear terminal console press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

When you run:

```
from os import system
system('cls')
```

you get exit code from system command and `0` means success.
You can assign it to tmp variable `_ = system('cls')` to get rid of it. But keyboard shortcut is much faster.

#### Python Console

When you try to run `cls` command you get this:

[image: Python Console]

That bold up-arrow is just a glyph that represents FORM FEED (ASCII value 12 or 0x0C - showed by next print statement). Helper script intercepts output and displays it instead of clearing console.

To clear python console you have to *right click* on text and choose *Clear All*.
This command doesn't have a shortcut, you can assign one in **File > Settings... > Keymap > Other > Clear All**.